# How to change the parent of a Google_DriveFile via update

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to update the parent of a Google_DriveFile object via setParents and then calling update on the file.  (So I'm trying to move the file to a different folder.)  From the API docs (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) it looks like this is possible, I guess I'm just doing something wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Everything works great except for moving the file.  The return from the update call is just the same file with the original parents (not the new parent).

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "'" . Configure::read('GoogleDrive.search_directory_id') . "' in parents"));
//debug($files); exit;

if (!empty($files->items)){
    foreach ($files->items as $file){
        if ($file->mimeType != 'image/jpeg'){
            // move to processed, do nothing else
        }else{
            if (!empty($file->downloadUrl)){
                $request = new Google_HttpRequest($file->downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
                $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
                if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
                    //file_put_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'drive_downloads' . DS . strtolower($file->title), $httpRequest->getResponseBody());
                    echo 'Writing file: ' . strtolower($file->title);
                } else {
                    echo 'Couldnt get this file!: ' . $file->title;
                }
            }
        }

        // let's move the file to the processed folder here...
        $newParent = new Google_ParentReference(Configure::read('GoogleDrive.will_processed_directory_id'));
        $file->setParents(array($newParent));
        $service->files->update($file->id, $file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know that as soon as I submitted this question, I found my answer.  I don't know what I was thinking.  I guess I looked at this for far too long.  I had to change

```
$newParent = new Google_ParentReference(Configure::read('GoogleDrive.will_processed_directory_id'));
$file->setParents(array($newParent));
```

to

```
$newParent = new Google_ParentReference();
$newParent->setId(Configure::read('GoogleDrive.will_processed_directory_id'));
$file->setParents(array($newParent));
```

Thanks!